# Can't install Ubuntu from an USB stick: AE_NOT_FOUND, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, live-usb, acpi

I bought a new laptop Lenovo Legion Y530 which came with Windows as default. I want to install Ubuntu and have a dual boot but can't make it work. At first I had to figure out how to make it boot from the stick, but now once I do that I get stuck at this error.

I get to the screen where I select a language and whatever I try afterwards (install Ubuntu or check disk for errors) I see the error in the attached picture:

[image]

How can I solve this? I tried with 3 different USB sticks. I used [this tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) to create the bootable USB with Ubuntu 18.04. I have 100GB of unallocated space which I want to format and put Ubuntu on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per this Arch Linux [thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233768) it's not an error:

> These kinds of "errors" have been discussed ad nauseam, it's simply
> the kernel telling you that the ACPI information received from the
> system seems to be incomplete in some way, update your BIOS/UEFI in
> hopes for a proper fix or ignore the error if you don't notice
> anything off with your system.
>
> (And please don't do something dumb like setting acpi=off just to get
> rid of these messages)

### What is causing the freeze is AFTER the ACPI messages

Below is a "good" boot log. What you need to figure out is which program **after** the ACPI entries is causing the lock up:

```
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.004000] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.004000] ACPI: Core revision 20170531
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.025175] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.XHC_.RHUB.HS11] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/dswload-210)
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.025179] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170531/psobject-252)
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.025206] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, (SSDT:xh_rvp10) while loading table (20170531/tbxfload-228)
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.032753] ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 9 successful (20170531/tbxfload-246)
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.033477] Security Framework initialized
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.033479] Yama: becoming mindful.
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.033493] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.034589] Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes)
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.035039] Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes)
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.035066] Mount-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.035081] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.035221] CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.035222] CPU: Processor Core ID: 0
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.035226] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.035227] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: View and update with x86_energy_perf_policy(8)
Aug 11 15:28:35 alien kernel: [    0.035228] FEATURE SPEC_CTRL Present
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but there is nothing after those logs. That is it, after it it just gets stuck. I managed now to proceed to install ubuntu 16.04 but after the installation is complete the final restart does not work. If i shut it down and then try to login it gets frozen.

Comment: Do you have a `530Y` or a `Y530`? Type `Lenovo Legion` into the Search bar above and you'll find lots of questions & answers to search through. Hopefully you can either solve your problem or refine your question with more clues to the problem.

Comment: I edited my post, I have Y530. I saw different answers to reset unity or change permissions, but did not work so far. I gave up a bit now and will try later. Hopefully i can make it work, if not will post a new question with more details.