# SGX disabled by BIOS in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: hard-drive, bios, 22.04, gigabyte, sgx

[image]

System information:

- Intel Core i5-10600K
- Gigabyte H510M H
- NVIDIA GTX 1050TI 4GB
- 500GB x1 NVME SSD (Installed Ubuntu), 2TB x1 HDD, 1TB x1 IDE HDD, and
  250GB x1 SSD

Operating system:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- kernel 5.15.0-27-generic

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset` and install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Ubuntu from an USB stick: AE\_NOT\_FOUND, AE\_ALREADY\_EXISTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064528/cant-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-stick-ae-not-found-ae-already-exists)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/intel/sgx-software-enable may be able to enable SGX via UEFI stuff for the next reboot, depending on whether your BIOS has explicitly disabled it or left it up to software.  The readme for that Intel software explains the possibilities.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with nvidia ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, but the SGX option literally did not exist in my BIOS, so it was impossible to change that.

A workaround was to reinstall with the "Minimal installation" option (as opposed to "Normal"), as well as not download updates or install third party software.

Answer (score 18):

For me the solution was exactly what the error message suggests: to enable SGX in BIOS.
I have an HP Elitebook, in the BIOS Security section there is a checkbox:

- Intel Software Guard Extension (SGX)

I set it to Enable (instead of Disable or Software defined)

Comment: Had the same with my Dell XPS 15. Thank you.

Comment: Had the same issue with an Intel NUC.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`sgx software enable`](https://github.com/intel/sgx-software-enable) to enable Intel SGX on Linux system Where the BIOS supports intel SGX.

> This application will enable Intel SGX on Linux systems where the BIOS supports Intel SGX, but does not provide an explicit option to enable it. These systems can only enable Intel SGX via the "software enable" procedure.

I tried it, it works.

Answer (score 6):

The SGX technology has a weakness called Poreshadow or L1TF.

https://support.lenovo.com/kr/en/solutions/ps500174-intel-software-guard-extensions-sgx-vulnerabilities
https://www.techspot.com/news/93006-intel-sgx-deprecation-impacts-drm-ultra-hd-blu.html

If you are not going to watch 4K bluelay video, turn it off.

Comment: I assume the disable by bios message means it's getting fully disabled anyway, can just leave it in that state or is something more required?

Answer (score 1):

In the case that I encountered, I couldn't solve it with "SGX software enable", but it was resolved when I reinstalled my linux and went to BIOS via

```
systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```