# SGX disabled by bios

Tags: asus, bios, sgx

SGX disabled by bios. After installing Ubuntu 22.04
system specs
i5 8th gen
memory-8gb

I re installed the OS but still the problem is not solved.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: ^^^Meaning: If the only thing happening is that message and the system boots fine to the desktop then there isn't any problem.

Comment: You may find an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406760/sgx-disabled-by-bios-in-ubuntu-22-04).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Intel Software Guard Extension (SGX), you need to enable this in the BIOS (and have the software prereqs in place to make use of enclaves). This is what this error message tells you.

If you just want to get rid of the error, you can use the [nosgx kernel parameter](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html). The [Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) has information on how to use kernel parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I was running an outdated kernel. I had held back problematic kernel versions a while ago.

The kernel headers for the Nvidia driver were no longer available, causing this issue for me.

Cleaning up all old kernel versions, updating to the current HWE for Jammy, and downloading the headers for the Nvidia driver completely solved this issue.