# How to exit Emergency mode?

Tags: boot, unity

I was installing Unity to play some games, after rebooting as asked the computer got into this emergency mode. I ran the journalclt -xb and it showed some errors:

```
x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible
MMIO CPU bug 
ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: set to normal was performance
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\PR.PR00._CPC] , AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
sda: Process ‘usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import —mount=dev/sda’ failed with exit code 1
video4linux: Process ‘usr/bin/snapd/snap-device-helper add snap_discord_discord /class/video4linux 0:0’ failed with exit code 1
pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
```

I’m super newbie at this, I don’t know what to do. Please help.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SGX disabled by BIOS in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406760/sgx-disabled-by-bios-in-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Your title merely asks how to exit Emergency mode. I believe Ctrl + D would do that, if a simple `exit` doesn't work. But I believe you need to enable SGX in the BIOS to solve your real problem.

Comment: The version is 22.04.01 lts. The link didn’t help though. I’m trying to learn about enabling SGX but it’s so confusing.