# Failure to install Ubuntu

Tags: asus, bios, lvm, firmware

I try to install ubuntu22.04.02 lts  in my laptop asus x540u models, at first time all things are working good only in steps 5 when i chose to erase the disk with LVM, so it contine to loading without stop or keep moving the other steps.
Also i want to know how can i fix this error:

> X86/cpu: sgx disabled by bios.
> Tpm_crb MSFT0101:00:[firmware bug]:acpi region does not cover rhe entire command/response buffer.

Thank you

Comment: It may help if you're specific with details; you mention Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, but not which product, ie. is this Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server using `subiquity` installer? or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop using `ubiquity` installer?   Please provide full details.  *You mention laptop, but loads of laptops are used as low-powered servers so please be specific with details*

Comment: Ubuntu LTS desktop

Comment: Please correct your question with that detail.... this isn't a forum, but a Q&A site, meaning answers will be to your question which mentions only release details & not if it's Desktop or Server still.  Comments are only that; ie. comments to the *Original Poster* (*and get removed once addressed; cleaner questions - ie. those without comments, tend to get faster responses*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SGX disabled by BIOS in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406760/sgx-disabled-by-bios-in-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: My be I found the problem، my pc don't support linux. So another question, can i update bios, and if this opération Don't affacte the système?