# Ubuntu installation error under Asus Laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation, asus

**Hi everyone ,
I have a small problem on my ASUS Notebook X540UP pc, which does not accept Ubuntu, as I managed to install it but with error messages.  In addition, I failed to exploit the system, it blocked several times.  Can someone help me.
Some body told me that : this pc does not accept other OS.  So how can I solve the problem.
**
[Erreur display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF26u.jpg)

Comment: look at this [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406760/sgx-disabled-by-bios-in-ubuntu-22-04) to solve SGX disabled by BIOS.

Comment: Thank you for help, but i didn't have in my bios, so how can i fix it ? How can i enable SGX if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Can you disable TPM in BIOS?

Comment: I don't found TPM!!! Existe only ''csm support'' and ''launche pxe OpROM policy''.

Comment: I tried to enable SGX in the bios but I can't find the option related to SGX.  
I installed an application from Intel ( https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058952/software/intel-security-products.html),
 to activate the SGX, and since the latter it showed that Intel SGX is activated. For information i update the bios from 314 to 316.
But in bios i don't found it (Intel SGX).
Can anyone help me how to enable from bios.

Answer (score 0):

when the SGX option did not exist in your BIOS, A workaround was to reinstall with the "Minimal installation" option (as opposed to "Normal"), as well as not download updates or install third party software. [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1414677/1698042)

Comment: Thank you, But i want to use a complet installation, for mor option and other things. So any idea for this?

Comment: minimal installation it is mean some packages will removed but after that you can add any of them

Comment: I tried to enable SGX in the bios but I can't find the option related to SGX.  
I installed an application from Intel ( https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058952/software/intel-security-products.html),
 to activate the SGX, and since the latter it showed that Intel SGX is activated. For information i update the bios from 314 to 316.
But in bios i don't found it (Intel SGX).
Can anyone help me how to enable from bios.

Comment: https://github.com/intel/sgx-software-enable