# ACPI Error: Only Ubuntu logo showing up

Tags: 22.04, acpi

I have a dual boot on my Razor laptop. I can log in to Windows without any problems. However, I have issues with logging into Ubuntu 22.04.

I see the following lines when it starts booting:
[image]

```
0.372401) ACPI Error: No handler for Reglon [VRTC] (00000000ddea6968) [Syst
emCMOS] (20210730/evregion-130)
[
0.372414] ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20210730/exf
ldio-261)
[
0.372431) ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.LPCB.ECO.RTEC due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psparse-529)
[
0.372441) ACPI Error: Aborting wethod I_SB.PCIO.LPCS.ECO. REG due to previo us error (RE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psoarse-529) /dev/nuw.On 1p6: clean, 730983/7684096 f1les, 28015775/30720000 blocks
2.606308] dell_sabios: Unable to run on non-Dell system
3.541455] nvIdla-gou 0000:01:00.3: 12c tImeout error e0000000
3.541492] ucs1_cc 0-0008: 12c_transfer failed -110
3.541531] ucs1_cc 0-0008: ucs1_ccg_Init falled - -110
```

and then it just shows me the following image:
[image]

It doesn't react to keyboard or mouse clicks. All I can do is log in to BIOS.
Before this issue I had another problem that had something to do with SGX. I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406760/sgx-disabled-by-bios-in-ubuntu-22-04) forum and enabled it as it was set to "software enable" before.

**EDIT**: Right before I was done with the day, I let the Windows install an update and shut down. The next day I encountered the above mentioned problems.

**EDIT2**: I logged into my Windows laptop and found the model of my laptop. Then I downloaded the Razor Intel ME Firmware update. However, when I clicked on the update I got the "This firmware tool is for use only with Blade and compatible system" error message. My model number is: RZ09-03006N92 and I downloaded the BIOS Updater and the Intel ME Firmware update from [here](https://mysupport.razer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4613/%7E/razer-blade-15%E2%80%9D-base-%282019%29-%7C-rz09-03006-support-%26-faqs).

Comment: As a first step I’d try the boot repair disk. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair